# cap aborted! SocketError: getaddrinfo: Name or service not known

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, ssh, capistrano

I'm a rails rookie, implementing Capistrano for my rails app to deploy on aws ec2 for the first time. Help will be much appreciated.

I have instantiated a ubuntu ec2 instance on aws. My Capistrano files are as follows.

**deploy.rb**

```
lock "3.7.1"

set :application, "railsapp.com"
set :repo_url, "git@bitbucket.org:UserName/my_app.git"
set :stages, ["staging", "production"]

set :deploy_to, "/home/ubuntu/myapp"


append :linked_files, "config/database.yml", "config/secrets.yml", "config/application.yml"
append :linked_dirs, "log", "tmp/pids", "tmp/cache", "tmp/sockets", "vendor/bundle", "public/system", "public/uploads"
```

**staging.rb**

```
set :rails_env, :staging
server ' xx.xxx.xxx.xxx', user: 'ubuntu', roles: %w(web app db)


set :ssh_options, {
  :user => "ubuntu",
  :keys => [File.join(ENV["HOME"], ".ec2", "stage1.pem")],
  :forward_agent => true
}
```

My aws security key pair is in home/.ec2/stage1.pem

When I run "cap staging deploy"

I'm getting this error.

```
$ cap staging deploy --trace
** Invoke staging (first_time)
** Execute staging
** Invoke load:defaults (first_time)
** Execute load:defaults
** Invoke bundler:map_bins (first_time)
** Invoke passenger:bundler:hook (first_time)
** Execute passenger:bundler:hook
** Execute bundler:map_bins
** Invoke deploy:set_rails_env (first_time)
** Execute deploy:set_rails_env
** Invoke deploy:set_linked_dirs (first_time)
** Execute deploy:set_linked_dirs
** Invoke deploy:set_rails_env 
** Invoke rvm:hook (first_time)
** Invoke passenger:rvm:hook (first_time)
** Invoke passenger:test_which_passenger (first_time)
** Execute passenger:test_which_passenger
cap aborted!
SocketError: getaddrinfo: Name or service not known
/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/socket.rb:231:in `getaddrinfo'
/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/socket.rb:231:in `foreach'
/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/socket.rb:626:in `tcp'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/net-ssh-4.0.1/lib/net/ssh/transport/session.rb:70:in `initialize'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/net-ssh-4.0.1/lib/net/ssh.rb:233:in `new'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/net-ssh-4.0.1/lib/net/ssh.rb:233:in `start'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/sshkit-1.11.5/lib/sshkit/backends/connection_pool.rb:59:in `call'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/sshkit-1.11.5/lib/sshkit/backends/connection_pool.rb:59:in `with'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/sshkit-1.11.5/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:155:in `with_ssh'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/sshkit-1.11.5/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:108:in `execute_command'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/sshkit-1.11.5/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:141:in `block in create_command_and_execute'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/sshkit-1.11.5/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:141:in `tap'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/sshkit-1.11.5/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:141:in `create_command_and_execute'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/sshkit-1.11.5/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:55:in `test'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/capistrano-passenger-0.2.0/lib/capistrano/tasks/passenger.cap:42:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/sshkit-1.11.5/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:29:in `instance_exec'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/sshkit-1.11.5/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:29:in `run'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/sshkit-1.11.5/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:12:in `block (2 levels) in execute'
Tasks: TOP => rvm:hook => passenger:rvm:hook => passenger:test_which_passenger
```

Comment: probably a typo in some hostname you are using. since you xed it out, it's hard to tell.

Comment: @phoet  this the host ip `server '35.154.168.195', user: 'ubuntu', roles: %w(web app db)
`

Comment: for me this problem was due to typo in `set :domain, "my.domain.com.au"` in config/deploy/testing.rb